# How to solve the error "No Protocol specified" for ClusterSSH

Tags: ssh, opensuse

I'm trying to setup ClusterSSH on my OpenSuse 15.1 - yet I'm getting an error and I've looked around and cannot find a solution.

```
mschumacher@Desktop:~/.clusterssh> cssh -l mschumacher 10.0.96.26
Connection to server failed -- (version 11.0)
No protocol specified
 at /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.26.1/App/ClusterSSH.pm line 1983.
```

In the file /home/mschumacher/.clusterssh/config I have..

```
#auto_close=5
#auto_quit=yes
#command=
#comms=ssh
#console=console
#console_args=
#console_position=
#debug=0
#external_cluster_command=
#extra_cluster_file=
#extra_tag_file=
#history_height=10
#history_width=40
#key_addhost=Control-Shift-plus
#key_clientname=Alt-n
#key_history=Alt-h
#key_localname=Alt-l
#key_macros_enable=Alt-p
#key_paste=Control-v
#key_quit=Alt-q
#key_retilehosts=Alt-r
#key_username=Alt-u
#lang=en
#macro_hostname=%h
#macro_newline=%n
#macro_servername=%s
#macro_username=%u
#macro_version=%v
#macros_enabled=yes
#max_addhost_menu_cluster_items=6
#max_host_menu_items=30
#menu_host_autotearoff=0
#menu_send_autotearoff=0
#mouse_paste=Button-2
#rsh=rsh
#rsh_args=
#screen_reserve_bottom=60
#screen_reserve_left=0
#screen_reserve_right=0
#screen_reserve_top=0
#send_menu_xml_file=/home/mschumacher/.clusterssh/send_menu
#sftp=sftp
#sftp_args=
#show_history=0
ssh=/usr/bin/ssh
#ssh_args=
#telnet=telnet
#telnet_args=
#terminal=xterm
#terminal_allow_send_events=-xrm '*.VT100.allowSendEvents:true'
#terminal_args=
#terminal_bg_style=dark
#terminal_colorize=1
#terminal_decoration_height=10
#terminal_decoration_width=8
#terminal_font=6x13
#terminal_reserve_bottom=0
#terminal_reserve_left=5
#terminal_reserve_right=0
#terminal_reserve_top=5
#terminal_size=80x24
#terminal_title_opt=-T
#title=CSSH
#unmap_on_redraw=no
#use_all_a_records=0
#use_hotkeys=yes
#use_natural_sort=0
#window_tiling=yes
#window_tiling_direction=right
user=mschumacher
```

I'll keep digging around to see if I can figure out what the issue(s) are, but hopefully, it will be something simple to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution:

Log in as root. Type in the command "xhost +", which should come back with "access control disabled, clients can connect from any host". Exit out of root and able to use cssh.